# jQuery run only once, even on back button press

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I have a page that loads an runs some jQuery.  If I refresh the page, it's fine because it only runs the one time on a specific action. However, if the jQuery runs, then I go forward a page, and then back a page. The jQuery will run again because it is still loaded from last time.  Is there something I can do that make jQuery only run once, even on a back button press?

Comment: you can use cookies

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: I don't get it, if you refresh the page it's fine, but if you click the back button in the browser it's not fine as it loads something from last time? Makes no sense to me!

Comment: i think you should mix a serverside language with jquery to achive this

Comment: @adeneo modern browsers tend to cache your navigation history so that when you press back the page isn't actually loaded from scratch so a page becomes stateful to some degree

Comment: Wouldn't that be great, if javascript kept it's state when navigating ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a state which is stored using a cookie/sessionStorage and bases on the cookie you can determine whether to run it again or not

Answer (score 0):

Do you use jQuery Ajax? give it property -> cache: false